# Generic wrappers for templates: optimization opportunities

Tags: c++, templates, generics, optimization, c++-cli

I'm trying to marry templates to generics with the accent on making access to primitive/value-typed properties as fast as (reasonably) possible, preferrably keeping it in C++/CLR. Consider this simple template:

```
template< typename type >
class value_wrapper {
public:
    type value;
};
```

and its counterpart:

```
generic< typename T >
public ref class ValueWrapper {
    ...
public:
    property T Value {
        T get() {
            if( T::typeid == System::Int32::typeid )
                return ( T )( ( value_wrapper< int > * )ptr )->value;
            ...branches for some other types...
            // if all else fails:
            return ( T )( Object ^ )( ( value_wrapper< gcroot< Object ^ > > * )ptr )->value;
        }
        ...
    }
    ...
private:
    void *ptr;
};
```

**Question 1.** When a generic's MSIL is turned into specializations for value types, is the code further optimized? Is it possible to check types here in such a way that, e.g., in `ValueWrapper<int>` branches for non-int types and type comparisons themselves will be optimized away?

Now, listing all supported types in every single method is somewhat painful, so I have made a separate function for this:

```
template< typename action, typename context_type >
__forceinline
static bool apply( System::Type ^type, void *value, System::Object ^*box, context_type context ) {
    if( type == System::Int32::typeid )
        return action().operator()< int >( ( int * )value, context ), true;
    ...branches for some other types...
    // if all else fails:
    return action().operator()< gcroot< System::Object ^ > >( box, context ), false;
}

struct get_value {
    template< typename type, typename result_type >
    void operator () ( result_type *result, void *ptr ) {
        *result = ( ( value_wrapper< type > * )ptr )->value;
    }
};

generic< typename T >
public ref class ValueWrapper {
    ...
    property T Value {
        T get() {
            T result;
            System::Object ^box;
            return apply< get_value >( T::typeid, &result, &box, ptr ) ? result : ( T )box;
        }
        ...
    }
    ...
};
```

Turns out this is about 3x slower than the original code.

**Question 2.** What can be changed here to allow the optimizer to make the second implementation closer in speed to the first one (ideally, with speed difference within 10%-20%)?

P.S. This is mostly about VC 2010. But if VC 2012 is somehow different in this regard, that would be good to know, too.

Comment: You might gain some speed by using a `case`. Second implementation is slower, and can likely not be made as fast as the first one, because you first construct a `T` and then assign to it. Moreover you put a `System::Object^` on the stack even though it's not needed in all cases, and there might be some overhead of the function calls.

Comment: @stijn Do you mean `switch( T::typeid )`? I don't think it's possible. As for the second question, I'm OK with, say, 10%-20% speed difference, just not 3x. Editing for clarity. (Also: in theory, inlining could help with function call overhead, AND detecting the unnecessity of `box` & removing it, AND getting rid of extra operations on `result`. It's all about the optimizer's abilities.)

Comment: oops, sorry indeed switching on typeid does not work

Answer (score 1):

After some tinkering and MSIL-eyeballing, I have an answer to the second question: just pass a `typeid` getter function instead of `typeid` itself. It seems to be much easier for the framework to request type information on each comparison, than to store it into some variable (the old `type` parameter) and reuse it.

With this approach, the slowdown drops from 3x to something like 5-10% (!).

Question 2 out, Question 1 pending.

The resulting code:

```
template< typename action, typename context_type >
__forceinline
static bool apply( System::Type ^type(), void *value, System::Object ^*box, context_type context ) {
    if( type() == System::Int32::typeid )
        return action().operator()< int >( ( int * )value, context ), true;
    if( type() == SupportedStruct::typeid )
        return action().operator()< SupportedStruct >( ( SupportedStruct * )value, context ), true;
    if( type() == System::String::typeid )
        return action().operator()< std::wstring >( ( System::String ^* )value, context ), true;
    // for both reference types and unknown value types:
    return action().operator()< gcroot< System::Object ^ > >( box, context ), false;
}

struct get_value {
    template< typename type, typename result_type >
    void operator () ( result_type *result, void *ptr ) {
        *result = ( ( value_wrapper< type > * )ptr )->value;
    }
    template< typename type >
    void operator () ( System::String ^*result, void *ptr ) {
        *result = gcnew System::String( ( ( value_wrapper< type > * )ptr )->value.c_str() );
    }
};

generic< typename T >
public ref class ValueWrapper {
    ...
public:
    property T Value {
        T get() {
            T result;
            System::Object ^box;
            return apply< get_value >( TypeGetter, &result, &box, ptr ) ? result : ( T )box;
        }
        ...
    }
    ...
private:
    void *ptr;
private:
    static System::Type ^TypeGetter() {
        return T::typeid;
    }
};
```