# Wrapping unmanaged C++ templates in C++/CLI for C#/.NET use

Tags: c#, c++, .net, templates, c++-cli

If this has been asked, please accept my apologies. I can't seem to find much on the subject. [Primitive types pass template parameter between c++ and CLI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4735507/primitive-types-pass-template-parameter-between-c-and-cli) is a similar question, bit I didn't find it very informative.

I have a native C++ DLL that exposes a template class (an instantiation of it, of course), and I wanted an analogue of it in C#. I'm relatively new to C#, but I know the closest thing is a generic.

My problem is how to wrap the C++ template in a C++/CLI template/generic so as to be able to use it in C#.

1. Is it even possible? I'm thinking this is impossible, because the CLI wrapper wouldn't know how to marshall the unmanaged, unknown type `T` into a managed type for C# consumption.
2. If it is possible, how do you go about it? If not, what are some general strategies you could use in similar situations?

Thanks.

Comment: C++ templates are instantiated at compile time.  The only possible way to could use them from managed code is by having it run a C++ compiler.  This is not practical of course.

Use the *generic* keyword in C++/CLI to declare generic types that are instantiated at runtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're talking about unmanaged `C++` then it's not really possible.

In general, passing anything complicated from unmanaged C++ to C# is a right pain.

The easiest thing to do is to write a simple struct in C++ that you can use to pass data between managed and unmanaged code. (In other words, a Data Transfer Object.)

Then write an unmanaged function (that uses a `C` signature rather than a name-mangled `C++` signature) which wraps the `C++` methods, and call that wrapper function from C# instead.

I've done this a few times, and it's very much more manageable than trying to call unmanaged C++ functions from C#!

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Yes, it's unmanaged C++ I'm talking about (I clarified this in an edit). So in your solution do you entirely bypass the managed C++ wrapper?

Comment: @KristianD'Amato Yes, in my code I wrapped all the C++ stuff with C functions, and copied necessary data from the complex C++ classes into very simple C structs.

Answer (score 1):

You stated that the template class is exported from the DLL already, which means it is an instantiated template class.

An instantiated C++ class has no difference than regular C++ class from the point of view of P/Invoke. Calling instantiated template class is possible and doable from C# directly without using C++/CLI although manually writing the wrapper code will be very time-consuming.

I have shared the way of doing this manually on stackoverflow at [C# pinvoke marshalling structure containg vector<structure>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4747171/c-sharp-pinvoke-marshalling-structure-containg-vectorstructure/16003004#16003004), but it will take you too much time to manually write a wrapper class this way, it may not be worth the effort.

The tool I wrote, [xInterop NGen++](http://www.xInterop.com) can generate the C# wrapper class for the template class. It can generate wrapper classes for any C++ classes exported from a native C++ DLL as long as the same DLL can be used from traditional C++ application.

You may want read the details at the links below on my blog web site.

[Advanced technology to wrap native C++ template class in C# automatically](http://www.xinterop.com/index.php/2013/08/01/advanced-technology-to-wrap-native-c-template-class-in-c-automatically/)

[Creating and Accessing Instantiated std::vector Template Class from .NET](http://www.xinterop.com/index.php/2013/04/19/creating-and-accessing-an-instance-of-stdvector-template-class-from-dotnet/)

I do have a plan to release an express version for free in the near future if the budget is your concern. So, if you have a small project with the need of calling a few C++ template class, you might be able to use the free version with limited features to create C# wrapper class. I also have plan to release generated C# wrapper(C# binding) for a couple of open source C++ projects.

(I am the author of [xInterop NGen++](http://www.xInterop.com))

Comment: I have been evaluating this tool for our company and have been very impressed with the level of coverage and the number of use-cases it fulfills. A very good product if you have a large investment in C++ and need to be able to consume it from C#/VB.Net applications.

Answer (score 0):

It's doable if you are willing to provide an explicit list of supported template argument types and managed<->unmanaged conversion functions for these types in the C++/CLI wrapper. [See the code here.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11920458)